# Cookies for website to website tracking

Tags: html, web

Fairly new to web development and I'm wondering if I can use a cookie dropped from my website to track user behavior from website to website.  We're trying to add analyics capabilities to our product so we can see the life cycle of an article on other websites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if the other website includes resources from your website and the user is running a browser with third-party cookie support enabled.

Comment: Thank you. Then maybe there is a better way. How can I track where a link we create ends up at?